# How can I make a custom 503 page on OpenShift?

Tags: openshift

I would like to change the default openshift 503 page that occurs when I am deploying my app. I did find [this](https://coderwall.com/p/ntq0gw) solution, but I am not sure where to put the python script.

I only have the PHP 5.4 application running (no cartridges), if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

There is not currently a way to create a custom 503 error message page.  What the other tutorial is doing is basically starting up a secondary web server when the primary one shuts down to just show a custom page while your application is deploying, but this is not actually a custom 503 error page.

Comment: is it possible to do it that way then?

Comment: Yes, you could copy all of those python files into your git repo and have it run there, or you could put them in your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR and call them via the action hooks.  His directions on the linked page were pretty good, should be able to just follow along with them.

Comment: ~/app-root/data on the server, you can also type cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR and you will change directories to the correct place.